# 3D graphing in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble graphing using Matlab, and was hoping someone could help.  I just want to hand the program a function like $z=x^2-3xy+2$, or whatever, and have Matlab generate a 3D graph.  From the tutorials I've seen online, it seems like this is difficult.  Can I not just hand the program that equation and the domain that I want, and have it generate a graph?  What code will generate that graph?  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to use the free software Maxima.

Comment: You've at least tried to read [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs.  From the examples I've seen, it just seems unnecessarily difficult to generate a graph.

Comment: The documentation for `meshgrid` has an example of [creating a 3D graph in three lines of code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) (two, if you fold the second line into the third). It would be nice to not need to go through the motions of creating a meshgrid, but that's how it is in Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, lets plot the function in the interval $x=[-2;2], y=[-2;2]$. As mentioned in the comments, this can be achieved in **Matlab** by the code

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2, -2:.2:2);                                
Z = X.^2 - 3*X.*Y + 2;
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

It can also be done in **Maple** by the following code

```
plot3d(x^2 - 3*x*y, x=-2..2, y=-2..2);
```

which is probably more intuitive. At last, one can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot3d%28x%5E2%20-%203%2ax%2ay,%20x=-2..2,%20y=-2..2%29;).

Comment: thanks for the help.  I used Maple at my last job, and so far I find it much more intuitive than Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is to use [`ezsurf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezsurf.html):

```
ezsurf('x^2-3*x*y+2')
```

or [`fsurf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html) in recent Matlab versions.